# What's the best way to pay tolls on a cross-country road trip in the US?

Tags: usa, automobiles, road-trips, tolls, washington-state

I'm driving from Virginia to Washington state later this month. In Virginia, I use an EZ-Pass device that automatically pays my tolls. But I understand that these devices are regional. When driving cross-country, am I best off just using quarters? Or can I buy 1-2 more devices to cover tolls across the entire country?

Comment: In a word: Cash.

Comment: wave of the future: Golden Gate Bridge no longer accepts cash. If you do not have a transponder, there are places you can pull off to buy a one-time ticket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which route you take you may pass through at least 2 or 3 Electronic toll collection systems you can find most of them on the [Government Services Administration](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/content/104326) page.

If you take the most direct route via West Virginia, Ohio, Indiana, Illinois and then via I-90 to Washington, you might need [EZ Pass](http://www.ezpassnj.com), [Mn Pass](http://www.mnpass.org/), and Washington's [Good to Go](http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/goodtogo/).

You can look at other states that have the Electronic Toll collection systems unaffiliated with other states like California, Texas, Florida, Oklahoma, Colorado, and Kansas.  So generally I wouldn't bother with buying the transponders from them just keep some cash on hand for now and wait until you get License Plate billing technology installed like in [Canada](http://www.407etr.com/) or [Israel](http://www.kvish6.co.il/).  California seems to be moving in that direction...

Comment: +1 esp. for the useful GSA link. FWIW however, MnPASS is only required if you want to use the "Express Lanes" on certain highways; the regular lanes remain toll-free. Similarly, the only mandatory toll facilities in Washington are the Route 520 Bridge and the Tacoma Narrows Bridge; no need for a Good to Go if you won't be taking them.

Comment: @choster Amended (slightly)

Comment: Florida and Colorado have license plate billing. Most states between VA and WA don't have many, if any toll roads.

Comment: @xpda True.  Didn't pay enough attention to those states.

Comment: Kansas has a few toll roads. Most of I-35 from just north of the OK/KS border, up to Topeka, then Kansas city is toll.  You may drive on a small portion of that if crossing the state from west to east.